# Knowing exactly where which computation process wrong in intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, exception

I have the following python code inside a large loop

```
arr_a[indx]*arr_b[arr_c[indx],]
```

and with one running, an exception occurred and it said index out of range, but there are two possibilities(indx is out of range for predictErr, or arr_c[indx]), how do I know which part goes wrong?

This problem also extend to some general case that when one write several operations in one line and when things goes wrong, it is hard to tell which part causes this, and note that the above mentioned expression is inside a large loop, which means one can not simply start a debug mode and find that out.

Comment: Can you be more clear about why you can't use the debugger?

Comment: ok, for example, for i in range(10000){indx=fun(i); arr_a[indx]*arr_b[arr_c[indx],] },  so indx is get dynamically, and you can't trace 10000 steps, can you?

Answer (score 0):

Add a print statement for each segment that might be to blame to see which one fails:

```
print arr_a[indx]
print arr_c[indx]
arr_a[indx]*arr_b[arr_c[indx],]
```